# How to add a clickable button in a List without triggering NavigationLink event?

Tags: swift, list, button, swiftui, navigationlink

I have a button in a list item and when I click on it, the NavigationLink's event is also being triggered.
I only want to trigger the button event. How to do it?
following is my code:

```
ForEach(self.cares,id:\.id){ care in
    HStack{
          if(care.markMode == "打卡"){
               Button("今日未打卡"){
          }
          else{
               Button("新增记录"){
               self.care = care
               self.showSheetNewMark.toggle()
               }
          }
          NavigationLink(destination:CareDetailView(care: care)){
              Text("\(care.nickname!)的\(care.subject!)")
          }
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `PlainButtonStyle` for button, as in below example

```
Button("新增记录"){
  self.care = care
  self.showSheetNewMark.toggle()
}
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) // << here !!
```